For SentencePieceBPETokenizer, Exception: Unk token `<unk>` not found in the vocabulary
I try to create a simple SentencePieceBPETokenizer without training.
from tokenizers import SentencePieceBPETokenizer
special_tokens = ["<unk>", "<pad>", "<cls>", "<sep>", "<mask>"]
test_tokenizer = SentencePieceBPETokenizer(unk_token="<unk>", replacement = "▁")
test_tokenizer.add_special_tokens(special_tokens)
print(test_tokenizer.token_to_id("<unk>")) # print 0

It makes sense so far, then I wrap the above tokenizer with PreTrainedTokenizerFast:
from transformers import PreTrainedTokenizerFast

wrapped_tokenizer = PreTrainedTokenizerFast(
    tokenizer_object=test_tokenizer,
    unk_token="<unk>",
    pad_token="<pad>",
    cls_token="<cls>",
    sep_token="<sep>",
    mask_token="<mask>",
    padding_side="left",
)

wrapped_tokenizer.push_to_hub('tokenizer-test', private=True)

and use it like this:
tokenizer_test = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("myHFusername/tokenizer-test")
print(tokenizer_test.unk_token_id) # print 0

so far it is correct too. But when I try to encode a paragraph, since the Tokenizer does not contain tokens other than those special tokens, all words should be tokenized to the unknown token.
print(tokenizer_test.encode_plus("I am a boy.", add_special_tokens=True))

However, it raises an exception:

Exception: Unk token <unk> not found in the vocabulary

Then, I double check whether the Unknown Token exists by:
print(tokenizer_test.vocab)

which prints: {'<unk>': 0, '<cls>': 2, '<pad>': 1, '<mask>': 4, '<sep>': 3}
Unknown tokens exist!
My question is: how do I resolve this issue?

Full Trackback:
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[13], line 1
----> 1 print(tokenizer_test.encode_plus("I am a boy.", add_special_tokens=True))

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py:2717, in PreTrainedTokenizerBase.encode_plus(self, text, text_pair, add_special_tokens, padding, truncation, max_length, stride, is_split_into_words, pad_to_multiple_of, return_tensors, return_token_type_ids, return_attention_mask, return_overflowing_tokens, return_special_tokens_mask, return_offsets_mapping, return_length, verbose, **kwargs)
   2707 # Backward compatibility for 'truncation_strategy', 'pad_to_max_length'
   2708 padding_strategy, truncation_strategy, max_length, kwargs = self._get_padding_truncation_strategies(
   2709     padding=padding,
   2710     truncation=truncation,
   (...)
   2714     **kwargs,
   2715 )
-> 2717 return self._encode_plus(
   2718     text=text,
   2719     text_pair=text_pair,
   2720     add_special_tokens=add_special_tokens,
   2721     padding_strategy=padding_strategy,
   2722     truncation_strategy=truncation_strategy,
   2723     max_length=max_length,
   2724     stride=stride,
   2725     is_split_into_words=is_split_into_words,
   2726     pad_to_multiple_of=pad_to_multiple_of,
   2727     return_tensors=return_tensors,
   2728     return_token_type_ids=return_token_type_ids,
   2729     return_attention_mask=return_attention_mask,
   2730     return_overflowing_tokens=return_overflowing_tokens,
   2731     return_special_tokens_mask=return_special_tokens_mask,
   2732     return_offsets_mapping=return_offsets_mapping,
   2733     return_length=return_length,
   2734     verbose=verbose,
   2735     **kwargs,
   2736 )

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_fast.py:500, in PreTrainedTokenizerFast._encode_plus(self, text, text_pair, add_special_tokens, padding_strategy, truncation_strategy, max_length, stride, is_split_into_words, pad_to_multiple_of, return_tensors, return_token_type_ids, return_attention_mask, return_overflowing_tokens, return_special_tokens_mask, return_offsets_mapping, return_length, verbose, **kwargs)
    478 def _encode_plus(
    479     self,
    480     text: Union[TextInput, PreTokenizedInput],
   (...)
    497     **kwargs,
    498 ) -> BatchEncoding:
    499     batched_input = [(text, text_pair)] if text_pair else [text]
--> 500     batched_output = self._batch_encode_plus(
    501         batched_input,
    502         is_split_into_words=is_split_into_words,
    503         add_special_tokens=add_special_tokens,
    504         padding_strategy=padding_strategy,
    505         truncation_strategy=truncation_strategy,
    506         max_length=max_length,
    507         stride=stride,
    508         pad_to_multiple_of=pad_to_multiple_of,
    509         return_tensors=return_tensors,
    510         return_token_type_ids=return_token_type_ids,
    511         return_attention_mask=return_attention_mask,
    512         return_overflowing_tokens=return_overflowing_tokens,
    513         return_special_tokens_mask=return_special_tokens_mask,
    514         return_offsets_mapping=return_offsets_mapping,
    515         return_length=return_length,
    516         verbose=verbose,
    517         **kwargs,
    518     )
    520     # Return tensor is None, then we can remove the leading batch axis
    521     # Overflowing tokens are returned as a batch of output so we keep them in this case
    522     if return_tensors is None and not return_overflowing_tokens:

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_fast.py:428, in PreTrainedTokenizerFast._batch_encode_plus(self, batch_text_or_text_pairs, add_special_tokens, padding_strategy, truncation_strategy, max_length, stride, is_split_into_words, pad_to_multiple_of, return_tensors, return_token_type_ids, return_attention_mask, return_overflowing_tokens, return_special_tokens_mask, return_offsets_mapping, return_length, verbose)
    419 # Set the truncation and padding strategy and restore the initial configuration
    420 self.set_truncation_and_padding(
    421     padding_strategy=padding_strategy,
    422     truncation_strategy=truncation_strategy,
   (...)
    425     pad_to_multiple_of=pad_to_multiple_of,
    426 )
--> 428 encodings = self._tokenizer.encode_batch(
    429     batch_text_or_text_pairs,
    430     add_special_tokens=add_special_tokens,
    431     is_pretokenized=is_split_into_words,
    432 )
    434 # Convert encoding to dict
    435 # `Tokens` has type: Tuple[
    436 #                       List[Dict[str, List[List[int]]]] or List[Dict[str, 2D-Tensor]],
    437 #                       List[EncodingFast]
    438 #                    ]
    439 # with nested dimensions corresponding to batch, overflows, sequence length
    440 tokens_and_encodings = [
    441     self._convert_encoding(
    442         encoding=encoding,
   (...)
    451     for encoding in encodings
    452 ]

Exception: Unk token `<unk>` not found in the vocabulary

